# recursive count number in c using function

Tags: c

I try to make a recursive program but it's doesn't work.
the program to count number in teks.
example :

```
input:
abcde1234
```

and

```
output :
4
```

this my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int count_digits(char s[]);

int main (){
    
    char x[1000];
    printf("input string (max 1000 character): ");
    scanf("%s", &x);
    printf("number of digits in the text = %i", count_digits(x));
    return 0;
    
}
int count_digits(char s[]){
    int j, digits=0;
    
    for (j=0; s[j] !='0'; j++)
    {
        if(s[j] >= '0' && s[j] <= '9'
        {
            digits++;
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

maybe anyone can help me to fixed it :) . my program still show output = 9 not 4.

Comment: Turn warnings on. The missing return statement would have been reported.

Comment: First, there is nothing recursive about this code. You could have replaced the loop with a recursive call to count_digits(s+1), I suppose. But as Paul says, your function needs to return something, and turning compiler warnings on would have told you about that.

Answer (score 5):

You have to return the calculated value. Add in the end of your function:

```
return digits;
```

By the way, you program in not written in recursive approach.

should be something like:

```
int count_digits(char s[]){

if (!*s)
    return 0;
return (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9') + count_digits(s+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- `scanf("%s", &x);` invokes *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type. The `&` should be removed.
- The loop condition `s[j] !='0'` is wrong. It should be `s[j] !='\0'` to stop at the terminating null-character.
- You forgot to add `)` at the end of `if` line.
- You forgot to return the result `digits` from the function `count_digits`.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int count_digits(char s[]);

int main (){
    
    char x[1000];
    printf("input string (max 1000 character): ");
    scanf("%s", x); /* remove extra & */
    printf("number of digits in the text = %i", count_digits(x));
    return 0;
    
}
int count_digits(char s[]){
    int j, digits=0;
    
    for (j=0; s[j] !='\0'; j++)
    {
        if(s[j] >= '0' && s[j] <= '9') /* add ) */
        {
            digits++;
        }
    }
    
    return digits; /* return the result */
}
```

Then, try to make the recursive version!

Comment: thank you bro. but can you explain me about why should '\0' not '0'

Comment: @RiandraPutra `'\0'` is the null-character, which is used as terminator of C String. `'0'` is a character code of `0` and it is 48 in ASCII. Strings need not contain `'0'`, so using it increases risk of out-of-range read or reading uninitialized indeterminate values.